# More controllers but less actions or less controllers but more actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-4

What makes you determine to create a new controller instead of adding more actions to an existing controller? Where do you draw the line and WHY?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What certainly does *not* get into the picture is the number of actions¹ -- at least in the sense that "oh, I 'm over 50 actions in this controller, let's start another one".

The guideline² should be: controllers are a logical group for actions that operate on the same type of object (the same type of *model* might be a better definition). If it so happens that you have a model so rich in functionality that there are 30 separate actions that can be performed on it, go ahead and put them in the same controller.

On the other side of the coin: if you have simple models and you find yourself writing controllers with only a few actions each, that should be a reason to feel good about the maintainability of the application rather than a reason to worry.

---

Notes:

¹ Of course, a controller with that many actions is a red flag for possible code abuse so the number *should* come into consideration -- just not as some kind of hard rule.

² And it's really a guideline -- the aim here is to build a maintainable system, not to follow some religious scripture.

Comment: "controllers are a logical group for actions that operate on the same type of object (the same type of model might be a better definition)". Does this sound like 1 controller 1 entity ?

Comment: @Elisa: It sounds like that, but there's also the possibility of entities being so closely related that they really belong to the same controller.

Comment: What makes 2 entities being so closed related that they get into the same controller?

Comment: @Elisa: The fact that they are related :) e.g. `Widget` and `WidgetCategory`. I suspect that you want to hear some hard criterion -- there isn't one.

Comment: ok it seems when it comes to facts software architecture is about feelings ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The major factor that should determine when to create a new controller is the logic/functionality they perform. You'll want to make sure you *[separate concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)*:

```
public class ProfileController {  }

public class MainController {  }

public class AccountController {  }

public class ShoppingCartController {  }
```

Each of the previous controllers are used to coordinate the communication between their corresponding domain services/models and their views.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, I keep all action as simple as i can, if they get big or too many then i see if i can creater helper functions.

I have a controller per DB entity if necessary.

So for example I would have a User controller, a Cart controller, an Item controller etc etc.

I dont think there are any specific rules. Its just about keeping it all logical. If its logical to you then thats generally all that matters, unless you are in a team, then it needs to be logical to everyone.

Hope this helps.